# installing sql server 2008 32bit on 64bit os

Tags: sql-server-2008, 64-bit, x86

Hey guys i am facing a problem installing sql server 2008 on Windows 7 x64. it gives some wow64 error. can some one tell me is it possible to install 32bit version on 64bit OS. if yes, then please explain how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to install SQL Server 2008 Standard 32bit on Windows 7 x64, but only the Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise editions of Windows 7.  You need SQL Server 2008 SP1 though, and cluster installations aren't supported.  SQL Server 2008 Enterprise will not install on Windows 7.  Microsoft have some doco on MSDN about it.

But as outlined in the comment above - the 64bit version of SQL Server is a much better choice.

What version of SQL Server is it?  And what is the error?

Comment: +1 - do not do it. There is NO Reason to go 32 bit on SQL Server, and in fact SQL Server is one of the products whree it makes logical sense to have a 64 bit process. 32 bit is going to come back biting the installer soon when he runs out of memory. And no, AWE Is not the same as a 64 bit process ;)