# Need 64bit SQL Server 2008 for Windows 7 64bit OS 

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldeveloper

I have Windows 7 64-Bit, and I have SQL Server 2008 Developer edition.

Whenever I am trying to install SQL I an error stating that I cannot install 32-Bit SQL Server on a 64-Bit OS, but in the SQL Pack it says it has both 32-Bit and 64-Bit.

Are there any links of where to download SQL Server 2008 Developer 64-bit?

Comment: What version of 7? Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/116067/installing-sql-server-2008-32bit-on-64bit-os This page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx lists the different versions based on processor architecture

Comment: Try the Microsoft site. There's a fair chance there's something on there about it.